# Change the data from a deserialization code

Tags: java, deserialization

I just wanna to know how can I change the data from a deserialization. My program needs to:

Asks the user if they want to change the students information and stores that new data in the text file.

Here is my code:

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Deserialization{

    public static void main(String [] args) {

       Student st1 = null;
       Student st2 = null;
       Student st3 = null;
       String opcion=null;
       Scanner lol=new Scanner (System.in);

      try {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("input.ser");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         st1 = (Student) in.readObject();
         st2 = (Student) in.readObject();
         st3 = (Student) in.readObject();
         do{ //HERE IS WHEREI WANT TO ASK MY USER AND REALIZE IT
            System.out.println("Want to change?\n");
            opcion=lol.next();
             lol.nextLine();
         }while(opcion.equals("y")||opcion.equals("Y"));
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      } catch (IOException i) {
         i.printStackTrace();
         return;
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
         System.out.println("Class not found");
         c.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }

      System.out.println("Deserialized File...");
      System.out.println("Student 1");
      System.out.println("Name: " +st1.name);
      System.out.println("ID: " +st1.id);
      System.out.println("Average: " +st1.average);
      System.out.println("Student 2");
      System.out.println("Name: " +st2.name);
      System.out.println("ID: " +st2.id);
      System.out.println("Average: " +st2.average);
      System.out.println("Student 3");
      System.out.println("Name: " +st3.name);
      System.out.println("ID: " +st3.id);
      System.out.println("Average: " +st3.average);
   }
}
```

lization part

Comment: yes you can change by using setter method of Student class, and the updated object you can save in text file.

Comment: Can you explain me a little beat please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a Student class like -

```
public class Student {
  private String Name;
  private int ID;
  private int Average;
  /**
   * @return the name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return Name;
  }
  /**
   * @param name the name to set
   */
  public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
  }
  /**
   * @return the iD
   */
  public int getID() {
    return ID;
  }
  /**
   * @param iD the iD to set
   */
  public void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
  }
  /**
   * @return the average
   */
  public int getAverage() {
    return Average;
  }
  /**
   * @param average the average to set
   */
  public void setAverage(int average) {
    Average = average;
  }


}
```

After deserialization you will get an Object read from a file, now you want to modify Student object.

```
 st1 = (Student) in.readObject();
 st2 = (Student) in.readObject();
 st3 = (Student) in.readObject();
```

Here st1,st2, and st3 Student object you have. 
You can modify st1 name by calling setter method of Student Object. 
For example if you want to modify student name you just need to call

```
st1.setName("modifyName");
```

After modify you can write st1 modified object in file in usual manner.